# how to create all possible orders in a specific length from a list of strings

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of strings that need to fit in 6 characters. The strings can be split but the characters in the string can't be randomized. The strings have different lengths (4 and 3 characters)

I tried a few things with itertools and know how to get all possibilities but not how to get only the possibilities with a specific length requirement.

It's ok to omit the first zero from the list entries.

An example of a list:

```
wordlist = ["0254", "0294", "0284", "0289", "027", "024", "026", "088"]
```

It would be ok to get combinations like `025427`, `254027`, `270254`, `027254` (0 and 4 of the list) and the obvious `027088`, `088027` (4 and 7 of the list) and even `272488` (4, 5 and 7 of the list)

I think the solution lies in itertools in combination with something else.

Comment: use a standard double loop. for each element iterate over all elements and concatenate, removing the leading 0 is needed

Comment: Thanks @SembeiNorimaki! wouldn't that make a triple loop? because the removing of leading 0 is optional. Also I've tried this with permutations and chianing but I still couldn't get a joined list with the possibilities with the right length. Could you give me an example how to do this?

Comment: In order to have a result of length 6 removing zeros is mandatory if both elements have length 4,  forbidden if both elements have length 3 and mandatory for 1 of the elements if you combine an element of length 4 with an element of length 3 (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a standard double loop and check if you need/can remove zeros to get the desired length

```
combinations = []
for i in wordlist:
    for j in wordlist:
        if len(i) == 4 and len(j) == 4:  # remove both zeros
            combinations.append(i[1:] + j[1:]) 
        elif len(i) == 3 and len(j) == 3:
            combinations.append(i + j)  # dont remove any zero
        else:
            combinations.append(i[1:] + j)  # remove first element zero
            combinations.append(i + j[1:])  # remove second element zero
```

This will give you all possible combinations (including matching elements with themselves)